# Changing the Value of an Input Box with JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change the value of an input box to 3.  What I have done so far is create the variable for an input box.  This variable is named "input".  Currently, the value of the input box is "20".  When I type "input" into console, here is what is returned:

```
<input value = "20">
```

Then I try to change the value of the input box by doing this:

```
input.value = 3;
```

Then when I type "input" into console, it tells me that the value is still 20.

```
<input value = "20">
```

So my question is, how can I make it return the value of 3 to me?

Comment: how did you checked the value console? is `input` correctly referring to right input element? Please share a working snippet using `<>`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following way:

```js
var el = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
el[0].setAttribute('value', '3');
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0])
```

```html
<input value = "20">
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the discussion about dispatching the event.

```js
const inputEl = document.querySelector('input')
const btn = document.querySelector('button')
const event = new Event('change')

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  inputEl.setAttribute('value', Math.random())
  inputEl.dispatchEvent(event)
})

inputEl.addEventListener('change', () => console.log(inputEl))
```

```html
<input value="20">
<button>Add</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Then when I type "input" into console, it tells me that the value is still 20.
>
> ```
> <input value = "20">
> ```

This is a common point of confusion.

The `value` **attribute** that the console is showing you is not the same as the input's current value. It's the input's **default** value. The *current* value isn't held in an attribute at all.

You're successfully setting the inputs current value by assigning to `value`. If you wanted to change its `value` **attribute**, you'd do that by assigning to its `defaultValue` property, or by using `setAttribute`.

```
input.defaultValue = 3;
// or
input.setAttribute("value", 3);
```

...assuming (as it appears from your question), that `input` is a reference to the input in question.

Comment: Crowder how would I do that?  i used input.setAttribute = 3;  but when I type "input" into console, I am still getting a value of 20 returned to me

Comment: @MartyMcFarty: Hit refresh, I added some code to the answer.

Comment: the input box that I assigned the variable "input" to is where you type in how many coins you want to place onto a bet (it's a gambling website) What I am currently trying to do is change how many coins would be placed via javascript rather than typing in the amount of coins manually.  However, when I change the default value or just the value of "input", it doesn't change how many coins get placed on bets.  It only changes what is displayed in the input box.  So when I click, say, red (on roulette), it still bets 20 coins on red rather than the 3 that the input box is displaying

Comment: @MartyMcFarty: Can't help you with whatever specific website you're working with. It sounds like `input` isn't a reference to the input you're thinking of. Fundamentally, once you get a reference to the relevant input: If you want to change the current value, assign to the `value` property. If you want to change the `value` **attribute**, assign to `defaultValue` or uset `setAttribute`.

Comment: input is for sure a reference to the input I am thinking of.  I can get the text displayed within input to be what I want it to be.  However, the amount of coins that would be placed doesn't change from 20.  If I were to click red even after changing the input value to 3, it would still place 20 coins on red, rather than 3.  I completely understand if you are not able to help me considering that you can't see the website I am talking about.  I just wasn't sure if there was some other way to change input, maybe by dispatching a keyboard input of "3" to input with eventDispatch?

Comment: @MartyMcFarty: After changing the input's `value`, you could dispatch an `input` event at it.

Comment: would you by chance know the code I need to put into console in order to do that?

Answer (score -1):

Here is that you can do:

In your HTML, give your input an ID

```
<input id="input1" value = "20">
```

Then in your JS:

```
document.getElementById("input1").value = 3;
```

Comment: Not my dv, but lets first understand how OP got this output at first place.

Comment: @Vinod Bhavnani can I give the input an ID from within the Chrome Console?  I'm not able to change the HTML itself as it is not my website

Comment: @MartyMcFarty I think you are not clear with the basics of this. Can you answer Gurviner's question?

Comment: @VinodBhavnani the input box that I assigned the variable "input" to is where you type in how many coins you want to place onto a bet (it's a gambling website)  What I am currently trying to do is change how many coins would be placed via javascript rather than typing in the amount of coins manually.

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct input box in your variable? If you do a console.log(input) and check the logs, it should display an element. When you hover over it, the browser should highlight the input box on your screen. See if that is happening

Comment: @Vinod Bhavnani yes, it is definitely the correct input box.  I can get what is displayed in the input box to change to 3, but if I were to click, say, red (on roulette) it would still place 20 coins onto red.  The only way I can currently get it to place 3 coins rather than 20 is to manually type "3" into the input box rather than changing the value of it with JS

Comment: Try changing the defaultValue as told by T.J Crowder